s3 life cycle managament in AWS for last 180 days
HI Im new to AWS im trying to s3 buckets which are all not accessed for last 180 days using cloudtrail events using python script lambda function but in response im getting all the buckets list in the account i need only inactive buckets for 180 days, did i missed anything in the script. Please let me know to achieve this. Thanks in advance
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Initialize Boto3 clients for S3 and CloudTrail
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    cloudtrail = boto3.client('cloudtrail')

    # List all buckets
    try:
        buckets_response = s3.list_buckets()
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': f"Error listing buckets: {str(e)}"
        }

    buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in buckets_response['Buckets']]

    # Calculate the date 180 days ago from today
    days_ago_180 = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=180)

    # Create a date range for the last 180 days
    start_time = days_ago_180
    end_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

    # List to store buckets not accessed in the last 180 days
    inactive_buckets = []

    for bucket_name in buckets:
        events = []
        next_token = None

        while True:
            try:
                if next_token:
                    response = cloudtrail.lookup_events(
                        LookupAttributes=[
                            {
                                'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName',
                                'AttributeValue': bucket_name
                            },
                        ],
                        StartTime=start_time,
                        EndTime=end_time,
                        NextToken=next_token
                    )
                else:
                    response = cloudtrail.lookup_events(
                        LookupAttributes=[
                            {
                                'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName',
                                'AttributeValue': bucket_name
                            },
                        ],
                        StartTime=start_time,
                        EndTime=end_time
                    )
            except Exception as e:
                return {
                    'statusCode': 500,
                    'body': f"Error looking up events for bucket {bucket_name}: {str(e)}"
                }

            events.extend(response.get('Events', []))
            next_token = response.get('NextToken')
            if not next_token:
                break

        # If no events are found for the bucket, it means it wasn't accessed
        if not events:
            inactive_buckets.append(bucket_name)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': inactive_buckets
    }

